# Outlook email - insert formatted signature at cursor (AutoHotkey?)

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, autohotkey

In Outlook 2010, i would like to insert a custom signature. I know i can created formatted signatures for normal and reply emails, which is nice, but i'd like to have more control over which signature (if any) is used.

So i started using AutoHotkey, but am having trouble making it do what i want. For instance, say i have three signatures; one full signature with all contact info, another with intermediate info, and yet another that's just a couple lines. What i've got works, except when i want to insert the signature after typing a message, since it inserts the signature at the beginning of the email. I want it at the cursor position. How can i do this? I'd like to figure out the AutoHotkey solution, but if there's a better one, i'm interested.

A snippet that does the third signature. I've got two others.

```
:*:]sig3::
html=
(
<html>
<body>
<div style='font-family:sans-serif;font-size:9pt;line-height:100`%;'>
<p><span style='color:#404040'>Thanks. -bill</span></p>
<span style='font-size:8.0pt;color:#404040'>IM: xxxxx</span>
<span style='font-size:8.0pt;color:#404040'>123-456-7890 x123</span><br/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
)
outl:=ComObjActive("Outlook.Application")
save:=outl.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.HTMLBody
outl.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.HTMLBody := html . save
return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save each snippet into a clipboard manager like [Ditto](http://ditto-cp.sourceforge.net/). Then set up your hotkeys to paste from the clipboard manager.

You can also do it entirely with AutoHotkey by saving and loading the snippets to and from a file using AutoHotkey's [clipboard functions](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Clipboard.htm).

Comment: The clipboard tip pushed me in the right direction. Using ClipboardAll, i've now got sig save and insert functions. Thank you!